# Refer to primitive operator in R

Tags: r, primitive-types

I'm a big fan of the `+` operator for string concatenation in Python.  I would like to extend/customize the `+` operator to do the same thing in R.

Here's what I have so far:

```
`+` <- function(a, b){
    if(is.numeric(a)){
        sum(a, b)
    }else{
        paste0(a, b)
    }
```

This works pretty well, but in some speed tests, performs poorly compared to the original/primitive `+`.  So, how can I refer to the primitive `+` instead of `sum()` in the second line of the function?  If I just use `+`, of course R gives me a `node stack overflow` from infinite recursion.

Comment: The answer I was looking for was `.Primitive("+")(x,y)`

Answer (score 1):

(The answer offered in the duplicate question is another alternative, cleaner perhaps in that it does not add another function.)

Save the primitive as another function. Here I'll use a "special" function `%plus%` (so that it can be inlined), but it could be simply `plus` if you'd prefer.

```r
`%plus%` <- `+`
`+` <- function(e1, e2) if (is.numeric(e1)) `%plus%`(e1, e2) else paste0(e1, e2)
1+2
# [1] 3
'a'+'b'
# [1] "ab"
```